# Why do I get only three of my total four Youtube-Playlists with the youtube api v3?

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

The following thing occours during my use of the Youtube API v3. I request a search to get all my Playlists, but the result contains only 3 of 4, the newest playlist is missing.
But when I try the API in the developer page I get all four playlists.

Developer page:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list?hl=fr#try-it

My Request:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=id&channelId=UCtEV5D0j6LwV0MqCnZ7H1AA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

In java application I use the API to do the same, here is my code that delievers only 3 of 4 Playlists:

```
public int execute(PipelineDictionary dict)
throws PipeletExecutionException
{
    // Initialize the search
    YouTube.Search.List search = null;
    // Response item
    SearchListResponse response = null;
    // Create the youtube object
    YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException{}}).setApplicationName("GartenXXL").build();

    try
    {
        search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");
    }
    catch(IOException e1)
    {
        throw new PipeletExecutionException("Failure during sending youtube search request");
    }

    // Set API-Key
    search.setKey(cfg_apiKey);
    search.setChannelId(cfg_channelId);
    // Set Request Query
    // search.setQ(queryTerm);

    // search.type("playlist"); oder  search.type("channel");
    search.setType("playlist");
    // Set Fields, filters onle the filds that are defined
    search.setFields("items(id/playlistId,snippet(title))");
    search.setMaxResults(50L);

    try
    {
        response = search.execute();
        //System.out.println(response.toPrettyString());
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    dict.put(DN_YOUTUBE_LISTS, response);
    return PIPELET_NEXT;
}
```

The resulting Json looks like:

```
 {
"items": [
    {
        "id": {
            "playlistId": "PLWWeimUpYTkhXubzYoPSqetvhCYZocaVj"
        },
        "snippet": {
            "title": "GartenXXL Ratgeber"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "playlistId": "PLWWeimUpYTkjCabIwPo0NuvMV_BPkC981"
        },
        "snippet": {
            "title": "Produktvideos - Top-Produkte von GartenXXL"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "playlistId": "PLWWeimUpYTkgEBjIryCrqms640yy4D_1d"
        },
        "snippet": {
            "title": "Rasenmäher-Videos"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Maybe one of your playlists was private